# MS Access: Can't complete the Output operation

Tags: vba

I'm not an experienced vba programmer and working with access is not my cup of tea. I've been asked to fix some errors in an MS Access 2010 VB application. The sole user previously ran the application on a 32-bit platform but now has migrated to 64-bit. This caused the aplication to break. I have made some progress but every issue I resolve another seems to appear.

The following piece of code

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptQLDExport", acFormatRTF, frm.txtDirectory.Value + "\QLD\All\QDATA.DOC"
```

is causing a runtime error 2587: Microsoft Access can't complete the Output operation

I have seached on the net for an answer but to no avail.

My development environment is Windows 7 SP1 (64-bit) and the application is running in Access 2010 (vba7, 64-bit). I'm willing answer questions to provide more information. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [forum post](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/OutputTo-Runtime-Versio-t1476141.html) suggests it is related to runtime versus full versions of Access (or Office). The suggested solution is to Copy the file `UTILITY.ACCDA` from the `ACCWIZ` directory to the same directory as MSACCESS.EXE

You would need to check licensing before distributing the file in your application installer, obviously.

**Update**: On a machine that fails, copy over ProcessMonitor (from technet; no install required). Filter to your application. Repeat the process and get it to fail. Examine the files that your application is trying to access and why they fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've seen the distinct between runtime and full version before. Can you enlighten me please?

Comment: Your suggestion did not work. I copied `UTILITY.ACCDA` from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ` to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14`

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I found out that `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ` was not a trusted location. I added it as a trusted location in the trust center. Re-run the application and it worked.

Comment: Hi @MitchWheat I've got a similar problem with Microsoft.Interop.Access and DoCmd.OutputTo, migrating from a 32bit Windows 2003 Server to Windows 2008 Server 64bit. I get the same error. Trying to find something with Process Monitor, I notice a NAME NOT FOUND error, while creating the PDF file. Any idea of what I can do for going on and searching for a solution?