# Getting MS ACCESS error when exporting to PDF (can't save file)

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, ms-access-2016

I had this issue for a long time, then I had this pretty consistent working but had to make a change on the database and now it's acting up again. **It's not always erroring out**, but very frequently. Once I hit resume it runs and will complete the process. The error message is "Run-time error '2302': Microsoft Access can't save the output to the file you have selected."
I have added two fixes, with no luck. Adding a temp file before creating it and opening the report before saving it. Error code happens at "DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, str_code, acFormatPDF, strFile, False" and all I have to do is to continue (Play button) and it works. What can I do to avoid this and be consistent since I run this automated and need to be able to create PDF's from this report without an error.
Thank you for helping. I see some posts online, but nothing really with a 100% fix. Maybe SAVE AS PDF, or anyone know how to fix this?

CODE:

```
     Function output(str_code, str_XYZ, str_loc)
            Dim fs As Object
            Dim TextFile As Object
            Dim strFile As String
            strFile = "\\E:\APPS\Dev_accdb\PDF\" & str_XYZ & "\" & str_XYZ & "- 
        " & str_a & "-rpt.pdf"
    
            Sleep 2000
            DoEvents
            'Added this from a post - add a empty file first - did not help
            Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set TextFile = fs.CreateTextFile("\\E:\APPS\Dev_accdb\PDF\" & str_XYZ & "\" & str_XYZ & "-" & str_TC & "-rpt.pdf", True)
            DoEvents
            Sleep 2000
            TextFile.Close
            DoEvents
        Sleep 1000
    'Added this from a post - OpenReport hidden view and then close later -- also did not help
        DoCmd.OpenReport str_code, acViewPreview, , , acHidden
        Sleep 4000
        'NEXT step is where this stops sometimes with a "can't save the output to the file you have selected"
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, str_code, acFormatPDF, strFile, False
        Sleep 1000
        DoCmd.Close acReport, str_code, acSaveNo
        Sleep 100
        
    On Error Resume Next
        DoCmd.Close acReport, str_code, acSaveNo
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        DoEvents
        Sleep 2000
   End Function
```

Tried to slow down with SLEEP, added a empty file creation and open report hidden. Nothing really works.

UPDATE 2023-06-08:
I have tried this "...copy the file UTILITY.ACCDA from your
Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\ACCWIZ
folder to
Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14
folder."
from [solution from another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21759975/ms-access-runtime-2010-2013-outputto-pdf-issue) and same here
[from yet another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733868/ms-access-cant-complete-the-output-operation). It's been running only for two days, but I will update here if this works.
Thank you for helping everyone. Just a note, there is nothing wrong with the variables and the paths.

Update 2023-06-15:
Tried above and not working. When I test with Access open, no errors. When I automate using marco to fire script, I will most likely stop some where in the loop as described. I am testing today what ValNik said in the comments.

Comment: First try after ``TextFile.Close`` add ``Set TextFile=Nothing``. And ``Set fs=Nothing``

Comment: When populating `strFile` what is `str_a` ?

Comment: To K J : I removed the server name, the paths are all fine.

Comment: to Tim Williams: All variables are fine, just passing strings to create the file name.

Comment: @ ValNik : I am adding this today, My other attemps failed from another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed to C drive for placing the file fixed it. No errors since 06/22.

Answer (score 0):

Try this reduced code using the mapped drive syntax - similar code works fine for us:

```vb
Function output(str_code, str_XYZ, str_loc)

    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = "E:\APPS\Dev_accdb\PDF\" & str_XYZ & "\" & str_XYZ & "-" & str_a & "-rpt.pdf"
    
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, str_code, acFormatPDF, strFile, False, , , acExportQualityPrint

End Function
```

Comment: I tried simplifying, does not fix this.

Comment: Then you probably are facing a network issue. So, write the file to a local folder, then copy it to the network folder.

Comment: @Gustac, I am changing the store location to C drive, and will test. thank you. Was not able to find a solution.

Comment: @Gustac, it did not fail yesterday. I will monitor couple more days.

Comment: changed to C drive for placing the file fixed it. No errors since 06/22. thank you.